# QtCreator - How to Disable Live Code Debugging?

Tags: qt-creator

The new QtCreator appears to constantly run some kind of "error checking" to see if the code will compile. This is slowing down my computer. How can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably what you are seeing is the ClangCodeModel plugin that does check your code in realtime.
You can disable it like this:

- **Mac:** (upper left menu)QtCreator -> About Plugins -> Search for
  "ClangCodeModel" and uncheck the checkbox. -> Restart QtCreator
- **Windows and Linux:** Help -> About Plugins -> Search for "ClangCodeModel" and
  uncheck the checkbox. -> Restart QtCreator

I don't encourage you disabling it though...it helps you writing better code and learning new things. To find out more about QtCreator integration of ClangCodeModel have a look [here](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-clang-codemodel.html)

Comment: Good answer, but I'd disagree about the advice.  If you're writing a decent chunk of code in one go then you will refer to functions/classes/types that you haven't implemented yet, and with the Clang Code Model you're hit with so many pop-up warnings and errors that it's like you've strayed onto a dodgy website.

A good compiler will provide you your errors and decent warnings - you can have suggestions turned on too. When you're trying to compile this is when you're saying "I think my code make sense now". That's the time you want feedback, not before.
Each to their own, I guess.